# Uncaught TypeError with JSON Get Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, typeerror

`main` is the JSON object's property that I want to get from the weather API, but I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'main' of undefined

What's wrong?

HTML code:

```
<!-- display current temperature in Fahrenheight (default) -->
<div id="temp"></div>
<!-- display user's curent location -->
<div id="pos"></div>
<button id="loc">Show my location</button>
<button id="switch">Switch Metric Unit</button>

// return temperature and weather conditions for user's current location
var temp = document.getElementById('temp');
temp.innerHTML = "";
var tempStr = document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML;
var latitude;
var longitude;
```

JS code:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    // pos = position.coords.latitude + ", " + position.coords.longitude;
  })};

  $.getJSON("https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude, 
    setTimeout(function(data) {
      $('#temp').html(celsiusToFahrenheit(data.main.temp) + "&deg;F");
    }), 1000)
```

Comment: The callback passed to `setTimeout` does not accept any arguments; `data` is undefined. `setTimeout` does not return any sort of value you can use as the second argument for `$.getJSON` either

Comment: In fact, why are you even attempting to use `setTimeout`?

Comment: Actually  `$.getJSON` code  need to be:- `$.getJSON("https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude, function(data) {
  $('#temp').html(celsiusToFahrenheit(data.main.temp) + "&deg;F");
});`  also  can you show us the content of `data` using `console.log(data);`

Comment: Also, because `latitude` and `longitude` are only assigned values within an asynchronous callback, they're not going to be available when you try to use them in `$.getJSON`

Comment: I actually meant to use setInterval() so that I can get the data continuously. But I defined latitude & longitude as global variables, so I don't understand why they wouldn't be accessible in $.getJSON?

Comment: I understand now, the solution you referenced was helpful. Because they're assigned values within an asynchronous context, the rest of the code will be executed before, which means the variables will still be undefined.